# For simple web application, how can you use ".main" as the URI extention in place of .php or .html ?

Tags: php, html

For simple web application, how can we use ".main" as the URI extention in place of .php or .html ? How can we change example.com/test.php to exmple.com/test.main, without actually renaming the file.

Thanks

Comment: Look up "URL rewriting".

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use the apache extension **[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)**. Here's a sample of what you can do.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.main$  $1.php
```

This will take any request with the extension `.main` and actually serve the file with the same name but extension `.php`.

Answer (score 0):

ModRewrite is a great solution for such things, however, to permanently have a different extension for you PHP files while they are still recognised and executed as PHP, use Apache's [SetHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#sethandler) module.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.main$ $1.php [R=301,L]
```

Also please see this Tutorial: An In Depth Guide to mod_rewrite for Apache http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, you would use the `Manage Handlers` script to assign the PHP FastCGI executable to `.main` file extensions.